# My ListView consist an ImageView and a TextView i need to get the Text from the TextView

Tags: android, listview, textview

My `ListView` consist an `ImageView` and a `TextView` I need to get the Text from the `TextView`.
int the position of my list where I press (onItemClick).

How can I do that?

The 1 class have a Button then when you press I moving to the next activity (CountryView)
and expect to get back from the next activity with a text (name of the selected Country)

The 2 classes have a `ListView` (`ImageView` and `TextView`) the data is getting from a database and showing on the `ListView`.

My problem is to get back to the 1 class the selected name of the country.

Thanks so much for helping!!!

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
    setContentView(R.layout.home);

   // final int recquestCode = 0;
    final Button btnCountry = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fromButton);
    btnCountry.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Intent pingIntent = new Intent("CountryView");
            pingIntent.putExtra("btnText", " ");
            pingIntent.setClass(Travel.this, CountryView.class);
            startActivityForResult(pingIntent, RECEIVE_MESSAGE);
        }
    }); 

    /*  Button btnSearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.searchButton);
    btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), ResultView.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }
    });*/
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (data.hasExtra("response")){
        Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.fromButton);
        CharSequence seq = data.getCharSequenceExtra("response");
        b.setText(seq);
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.country);

    mListUsers = getCountry();
    lvUsers = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.countrylistView);
    lvUsers.setAdapter(new ListAdapter(this, R.id.countrylistView, mListUsers)); 

   // lvUsers.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
   // String extraMsg1 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("extra1");

    lvUsers.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id)
        {
            // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
            //textItem=view;
            //         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) view).getText(),
            //       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Intent pongIntent = new Intent();
            // lvUsers.getItemAtPosition(position);

            t = (TextView) view;
            Log.v("fffvd"+t, null);
            t.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("btnText"));
            String strText = t.getText().toString();

            //((TextView) view).getText().toString()

            pongIntent.putExtra("response",strText);
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,pongIntent);
            finish();

            // startActivity(new Intent(CountryView.this,TravelPharmacy.class)); 
        }
     });
}

public ArrayList<Country> getCountry(){             
    DBHelper dbAdapter=DBHelper.getDBAdapterInstance(this);
    try {
        dbAdapter.createDataBase();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.i("*** select ",e.getMessage());
    }
    dbAdapter.openDataBase();       
    String query="SELECT * FROM Pays;";
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> stringList = dbAdapter.selectRecordsFromDBList(query, null);
    dbAdapter.close();

    ArrayList<Country> countryList = new ArrayList<Country>();
    for (int i = 0; i < stringList.size(); i++) {
        ArrayList<String> list = stringList.get(i);
        Country country = new Country();
        try {
            //country.id = Integer.parseInt(list.get(0));
            country.pays = list.get(1);
        //  country.age = Long.parseLong(list.get(2));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("***" + TravelPharmacy.class.toString(), e.getMessage());
        }
        countryList.add(country);
    }
    return countryList;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    //     adapter.imageLoader.stopThread();
    lv.setAdapter(null);
    super.onDestroy();
}

public OnClickListener listener=new OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0)
    {
        //       adapter.imageLoader.clearCache();
        ((BaseAdapter) adapter).notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
};
```

**CountryAdapter Class**

```
public class CountryAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Activity activity;
    private String[] data;
    private  LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    // public ImageLoader imageLoader; 

    public CountryAdapter(Activity a, String[] d)
    {
        activity = a;
        data=d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public  class ViewHolder
    {
        public TextView text;
        public ImageView image;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        View vi=convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView==null)
        {
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.singlecountry, null);
            holder=new ViewHolder();
            holder.text=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.text);;
            holder.image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.image);
            vi.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
            holder=(ViewHolder)vi.getTag();

        holder.text.setText("item "+data[position]);
        holder.image.setTag(data[position]);
        return vi;
    }
}
```

**ListAdapter Class**

```
private class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Country> {  // --CloneChangeRequired
    private ArrayList<Country> mList;  // --CloneChangeRequired
    private Context mContext;

    public ListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,ArrayList<Country> list) { // --CloneChangeRequired
        super(context, textViewResourceId, list);
        this.mList = list;
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View view = convertView;
        try{
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = vi.inflate(R.layout.singlecountry, null);    // --CloneChangeRequired(list_item)
        }
        final Country listItem = mList.get(position);   // --CloneChangeRequired                
        if (listItem != null) {
            // setting singleCountry views                      
        //  ( (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_id) ).setText( listItem.getId()+"");
            ( (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text) ).setText( listItem.getPays() );
            //((ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.image)).setImageDrawable(drawable.world);
            //( (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_age) ).setText( listItem.getAge()+"" );

        }}catch(Exception e){
            Log.i(CountryView.ListAdapter.class.toString(), e.getMessage());                
        }
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: plz post code so that we can understand your senario

Answer (score 0):

When you add things to the list, you can add hashmaps to the arraylist which the adapter looks at. Then you can grab the values which are name value pairs.

Comment: I don't add anything to my list i get it from a Database,Thanks for helping!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to get the position of the list you clicked, Its simple you can use OnItemClickListener as follows

```
YourList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
                           int position=arg2;
                          // where position is the clicked position 

    }   }
```

If you stored your data in String array pass this position say array[position] to string array you can get the Text..

Comment: I need to get the text in my list (each item have an image and text) in the right position

Comment: Are you storing your values from Database in string array or something else?

Comment: i am not storing i am just reading the value from a database and showing that in a ListView

Comment: can you post your code?Also check this link this may give you any idea.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297011/android-search-array-and-retrieving-audio-files

Comment: I agree. Code would be useful. It sounds like you are just fishing for the complete code.